# Pick n random elements from set1 not present in set2

Tags: python, random, set

I would like to pick `n` random elements from `set1` that are not present in `set2`, if there are `n` such elements. If there are not, only those that are different should be returned or an empty set in the worst case.

Example 1:

- input: `n=2`, `set1={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`, `set2={0,2,4,6}`
- example possible output: `{1,5}` (other possible outputs: `{1,3}`, `{1,7}`, `{3,5}`, `{3,7}`, `{5,7}`)

Example 2:

- input: `n=5`, `set1={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`, `set2={0,2,4,6}`
- single possible output: `{1,3,5,7}` since there are only 4 choices and number of elements to choose is 5

Comment: Are the elements in the lists always unique? If so, the first step is to convert your lists to sets (with `set(list1)` and `set(list2)`) and then do a set difference.

Comment: Good point, let me change the question to use sets instead.

Comment: But converting the list to a set is also a valid approach.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński the question has been raised because the usage of set depends on whether or not you want the repeating elements, if there are any, to stay.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński I think mentioning the changes you have made in your question will help the answers already given to stay relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a set of unique values and return either `n` random elements from it, or if `n` is larger than the population return all elements:

```
def random_unique(x, y, n):
    ''' returns n random elements from set x not found in set y '''
    unique = x - y
    return set(random.sample(unique, min(n, len(unique))))
```

In action:

```
x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}    
y = {0, 2, 4, 6}

random_unique(x, y, 2)
{3, 5}

random_unique(x, y, 10)
{1, 3, 5, 7}
```

Comment: This solution will loose duplicates in first list

Comment: Yes, he will need to clarify his question if wants to have duplicates in list 1

Comment: Quote (Krzysztof Słowiński): "But converting the list to a set is also a valid approach"... shouldn't be a problem here

Answer (score 2):

In two lines (we could make it one, but it's a little ugly), using sets and [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
diff = set(list1).difference(list2)
random.sample(diff, min(len(diff), n))
```

Original solution (preserving duplicates in `list1`, as well as order, which doesn't really matter for random samples):

```
diff = [x for x in list1 if x not in set(list2)]
random.sample(diff, min(len(diff), n))
```

If you don't care about preserving duplicates, then set difference is indeed the way to go. Checking the timing between the two implementations with the following:

```
list1 = np.arange(10000)
list2 = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000)
```

we get:

- set difference: `1.15 ms ± 58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`
- list comprehension: `1.13 s ± 44.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- list comprehension with set pre-defined: `1.47 ms ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

That's a factor of 1000 faster for sets! Not much of a difference between `set.difference` and the list comprehension though if we have already built the set, but what difference is there appears to be significant (those standard deviations are tiny!).

Comment: If you are converting the list to a set, then using set difference `set1 - set2` makes things simple

Comment: I don't think converting everithing to set is correct because in first list there can be repeated elements that are lost in conversion to set. list1=[1,2,2,3,4,5] l2=[3,5], using set output will be [1,2,4], keeping first as list [1,2,2,4]

Comment: @DDS comment is correct. You only want to convert the list you are comparing *against* to a set. You do this because checking membership of a set is faster than checking membership of a list (`O(1)` vs. `O(n)`), and converting is fast. If you don't want to preserve possible duplicates (or order), then you can convert both to a set.

Comment: True. The question is not clear on that part, whether the duplicates are to be considered or not.

Comment: @RaviTeja granted! I see you and others have asked for clarification. I will leave my answer as-is. If OP doesn't care about duplicates, then this is not the way to go.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have changed the question to use sets as it was the assumption that elements in the lists are unique, but it is best captured by using sets.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly!